# SQL query for average calculations range wise

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like know how to write a query to  calculate the range wise percentage of students . Below is the table.

Range is as follows ,0-35%, 35-50%,50-75%,>75%

```
 Std   Name   Subject  Marks(20)
   2   Vinay   eng      17
   2   Vinay   math     16
   2   Vinay   hindi    15
   2   Rohan   eng      14
   2   vas     mat      16
   2   dheer   eng      15
   2   dheer   math     14
   2   dheer   hindi    11
   2   Bhas    eng      15
   2   Bhas    math     19
   2   Bhas    hindi    17
```

P.s Above data is for a Standard, how to write a query for calculating range wise percentage of students.

Output excepted as

```
Std Subject 0-35 35-50 50-75 >75
2   Eng      =    =     =     =
2   Mat      =    =     =     =
2   Hindi    =    =     =     =
```

Immediate help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name, AVG(Marks)
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

Comment: Minor correction: Wasn't the question about the average over all students who participated in all three exams? Thus, `SELECT AVG(avg_marks) FROM (statement in answer);` with `avg_marks` = calculated average in the answer?

Comment: @daniel.neumann, the question wasn't terribly clear, but you could be right.

Comment: I agree (wasn't sure myself) :-) .